# Create Facebook Android Key hash from apk file

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

First I'm not an Android developer and I know almost nothing about it .
as a vbulletin forum owner , I've got vbulletin android application .
I got it by filling a multi-step web form with data ( api key , facebook application id , secret , site name .. etc ) .. no development .. I get only a .apk file at the end .. so I have no android development environment installed .. no key store ( I don't even know what key store is ) .. the application has integrated facebook login but when I try to use it it asks for Key Hash .. is there a way to generate that .. thank you

Comment: If you install the Android SDK (https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html), you'll have the keystore at ~/.android/debug.keystore. Then you can generate the Key Hash.

Comment: thank you .. I will install it and come back

Answer (score 0):

How to create a key hash from a keystore file is in [Facebook Developer site](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started).

On OS X:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

On Windows:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %HOMEPATH%\.android\debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

If you want to upload your app to Google Play Store(not for debugging), you have to create another keystore file for release and use the same keystore file whenever you update the app. **DO NOT LOSE YOUR KEYSTORE FILE**.

See [Signing Your Applications](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html).

Create a key hash from the keystore for release again and register it to Facebook.